# TypeError: takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

```
class DLLNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data, prev_link, next_link):  
        self.data = data
        self.prev_link = prev_link
        self.next_link = next_link


class DoublyLinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def add_head(self, add_obj):
        self.head=DLLNode(add_obj,None,self.head)
```

---

```
>>> x=DoublyLinkedList
>>> x.add_head(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    x.add_head(1)
TypeError: add_head() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: A little explanation on what you are doing instead of just some code would be a better way of asking your question. Currently, the reader has to guess the question.

Answer (score 6):

Guessing x isn't counting as an argument because it's not getting instantiated right.

```
x = DoublyLinkedList()
```

not

```
x = DoublyLinkedList
```

not including parens assigns the `DoublyLinkedList` module object to x, it doesn't create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
x = DoublyLinkedList
```

you assign the class `DoublyLinkedList` to `x`, not an instance of it. `add_head` being an instance method, it cannot be called on the class directly. Instead, you need to use

```
x = DoublyLinkedList()
x.add_head(1)
```

This way, python will be able to substitute `self` with `x`, and you will have 2 arguments to your call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the object when assigning to x

```
 x = DoublyLinkedList()
```

The former syntax (DoubleLinkedList) is allowed because classes are valid as objects.